# Can't convert string to float because of '.'?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, floating-point

I need to round the string values of a column in my dataframe up to 2 decimal cases, so I started by converting them to floats using astype(float) and then using round(2).
Ex:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float).round(2)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

I thought the dots would be no problem, is there something I'm missing here?

Edit: It's a huge amount of data, so there could be unexpected values, but after filtering it to testing samples the error continues.

Edit2: Turns out I still had invalid data even after filtering the sheet, so sorry for the seemingly dumb question lol. mozways's solution worked fine.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data of where you are getting an error?

Comment: it's telling you the whole string is just `'.'`

Comment: Only numeric values, some (strings in the format of) integers and some floats up to 4 decimal cases, so 543; 787.345; 628.5743; 25...

Comment: @LucasAlves that is clearly untrue, because Python is telling you that you cannot convert the string `'.'` (literally just a dot) to float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert string to numeric without errors upon invalid data, use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['col'] = pandas.to_numeric(df['col'], error='coerce').round(2)
```

Comment: question is whether OP is expecting the column to contain elements that just have `'.'`

Comment: @timgeb not sure I follow you, if the goal is to round, then the input must be a float. OP can always fillna back the invalid data if needed

Comment: well, I just meant that OP's code *should* throw an error if `'.'` is an unexpected value

Comment: Yes, sure, it's better to know if and why the data is incorrect ;)

Comment: It's a 10 year old excel sheet with manual inputs that had never been treated before, so some invalid values were expected, but I searched specifically for special characters and never found any, maybe I did it wrong. But the error coerce was really helpful, thank you. I then replaced the NaT values with 0 and it's going fine again.